# Aptness and meaning: 'circumscribe a notion'?

Tags: word-usage

[Source](http://strategicstudiesinstitute.army.mil/pubs/parameters/Articles/1995/christop.htm): *Unjust War ...*, by **Paul Christopher**, from *Parameters* Autumn 1995, pp 4-8.

> Military leaders may privately make recommendations to the national leadership when they are asked for them, but they are prohibited from establishing or publicly influencing political objectives. Even the notion of resignation on principle seems **circumscribed** where decisions on the use of military forces are at issue. A military officer's resignation when called to arms, especially that of a senior officer, would constitute a public statement about that officer's assessment of the political objectives. Just as officers ought not to fight when the President decides against the use of force, they ought not to refuse to fight when the President orders them to.

Is ['circumscribe'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/circumscribe) apt? Here's my guess of the sentence with what I bolded:
 Even the notion of resignation [based] on principle[s] [of opposing a war] seems <s>**circumscribed**</s> [too blatant or overt] where [the resignation would derive from] decisions
on the use of military forces [that] are at issue.

Footnote: [This helpful comment](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21874/to-what-degree-are-soldiers-guilty-for-diligently-fighting-for-their-corrupted#comment49696_21874) introduced me to this article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, *circumscribed* here means "limited/constrained", not "too blatant".  It means the military leaders have very limited personal choice when called to arms by the executive.

When called upon to carry out an order from the executive (i.e. the President), a military leader who disagreed in principle with the order would not have the option of resigning his post, as that "would constitute a public statement about that officer's assessment of the political objectives".

See 1a [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circumscribed).

P.S. "Notion" was not the best choice of word in that sentence. *Prerogative* would be clearer.